# How to bind a Data Source?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jndi, sqldatasource

I'm getting an error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'netLogsDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'abcDataSource' defined in 
com.kinsale.submclrmgr.config.DataConfig: Bean instantiation via factory 
method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'abcDataSource' threw exception; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: 
Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'dataSource/abc'; nested 
exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dataSource/abc] is 
not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dataSource].
```

I am trying to figure out how to bind my data source, however the documentation I've found isn't helpful. there is a JndiTemplate that I can use to bind the data source, passing the parameters of String name and Object object, but nothing I can find tells me anything about the object.

What is the object that I bind to the name of the data source? And is it the name of the Bean I am creating or the name of the Resource in the context.xml?

Here is the Bean -

```
@Bean(name="abcDataSource")
public DataSource abcDataSource(){

JndiDataSourceLookup jndi = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
jndi.setResourceRef(true);

return jndi.getDataSource("dataSource/abc");
```

Here is the use of the bean -

```
@Resource(name="abcDataSource")
private DataSource ds;
```

Here is the context.xml entry (I do have the correct username and password)-

```
<Resource 
name="dataSource/abc" 
auth="Container"
type="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
URL="jdbc:mysql://abc/db_netlogs" />
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant elements and code to replicate your issue.

Comment: are you using spring ?

Comment: yes, I am using Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, the following dependency needs to be in the pom.

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

As soon as I added that, everything worked.